# Learning About constructors in Python

Tags: constructor

I have recently learnt about Exception Handling concepts. I am not able to understand why self.arg=arg doesnt work whereas self.msg=arg works in the below code.

```
class MyException(Exception): 
    def init(self,arg): 
        self.msg=arg 

def check(key,value): 
    print('Name={} Balance={}'.format(key,value)) 
    if(v<2000): 
        raise MyException('Balance amt is less in the account of ',key)

bank={'Raj':5000,'Vikas':10000,'Nishit':500,'John':321211}
for k,v in bank.items(): 
    try: 
        check(k,v) 
    except MyException as obj: 
        print(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work. You're basically assigning the value of the argument *arg* to the instance variable *arg*, no conflict there, a classic example that can be found [here in Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables).

Maybe you mistyped, used a symbol from another alphabet, or forgot a spacebar on that line? Without the error message all I can do is guess. So try replacing *msg* in your working code with *arg* once again, it may fix the problem.

By the way, it would be easier to use f-strings instead of formatting:

```
f'Name={key} Balance={value}'
f'Balance amt is less in the account of {key}'
```

It's shorter, you don't have to worry about messing up the order or number of arguments, and the code is more readable.